# ftp_put not uploading file

Tags: php, ftp

I have a script that upload a file through FTP, but it stops on ftp_put.

This is a summary of the script:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, £ftp_pass))
    $client->putLog("Login done");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $fileName, "../tmp/" . $userId . "/" . $fileName, FTP_BINARY))
    $client->putLog("File uploaded through ftp");
else
    $client->putLog("Upload: " . print_r(error_get_last(), true));
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The $client->putLog is a function that write string data in a logfile.
What is written in the logfile is:

```
Login done
Upload: Array
(
[type] => 2
[message] => ftp_put() [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: Type set to I
[file] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\test\script\upload.php
[line] => 124
)
```

On the ftp server there is Filezilla Server, that seems to receive some of the commands:

```
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> USER ftpuser
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> 331 Password required for ftpuser
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - (not logged in) (ip)> PASS ************
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - ftpuser (ip)> 230 Logged on
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - ftpuser (ip)> PASV
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - ftpuser (ip)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (95,110,184,28,170,145)
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - ftpuser (ip)> TYPE I
(000364)13/10/2015 17:01:12 - ftpuser (ip)> 200 Type set to I
(000364)13/10/2015 17:02:45 - ftpuser (ip)> QUIT
(000364)13/10/2015 17:02:45 - ftpuser (ip)> 221 Goodbye
(000364)13/10/2015 17:02:45 - ftpuser (ip)> disconnected.
```

I started even a wireshark session, and all I received (with a ftp filter) is:

```
Request command: USER
Request command: PASS
Request command: PASV
Request command: TYPE I
Request command: QUIT
```

Suggestion on why this does not work?

By the way, on another server it works perfectly...

Comment: Do your client under any NAT/Firewall??

Comment: Does the `ftp_pasv` return true?